# count records by specifying many fields and many count clauses on sql oracle

Tags: oracle, group-by, count

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM PATIENT_MED_SPEC
```

which gives this result:

```
NUM_MALADE| NUM_MED| SPECIALITE
----------+--------+------------
3          53       Traumatologue
3          85       Anesthésiste
3          126      Radiologue
6          34       Pneumologue
6          85       Anesthésiste
6          114      Traumatologue
6          135      Anesthésiste
13         4        Orthopédiste
13         8        Cardiologue
13         114      Traumatologue
21         19       Traumatologue
21         64       Radiologue
21         135      Anesthésiste
23         4        Orthopédiste
23         8        Cardiologue
23         88       Cardiologue
```

And I want to get the result below using `count` and `group by` clauses

```
NUM_MALADE| count_MED| count_SPEc
----------+----------+------------
3          3          3
6          4          3
13         3          3
21         3          3
23         3          2
```

i.e for every `MALADE` (patient) we count the `MEDECIN`'s 
(doctors) number and the number of `SPECIALITES` concerned

Comment: You need `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `COUNT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT MALADE, COUNT(*) AS count_MED, COUNT(DISTINCT SPECIALITE) AS num_SPEC
FROM PATIENT_MED_SPEC
GROUP BY MALADE
```